# Flexbox not working correctly with Aurelia (Webpack starter kit)

Tags: css, flexbox, aurelia

Given some very basic html using flexbox, I can achive a screen with a header, footer and a content area that fills all the space in between:

```
<html>
   <body style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1">
      <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">Header</div>
      <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;flex-grow:1">Content Area</div>
      <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row">Footer</div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Header displays at top, footer at the very bottom.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++
+ Header
+ Content Area
+
+
+
+
+ Footer
+++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

However, if I try to achieve the same thing within Aurelia (using the webpack starter kit) the grow seems to be ignored on both the body and the content elements.

**index.ejs -- comes with starter kit**  I added styling to original file

```
<body aurelia-app="main" style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1">
```

**app.html** -- changes to original starter kit file

```
<template>
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">Header</div>
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;flex-grow:1">Content Area</div>
   <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">Footer</div>
</template>
```

I also tried adding flex to  `<template style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1">`

Everything looks good when you inspect the page -- in fact, looks almost exactly like the basic html example.  However, the `body` and the `div` containing the Content Area do not grow to fill the height of the page.

I tried to get an example working in Plnkr but it actually has the same problem as Aurelia.  I noticed that it is using `shadow` element just like Aurelia does -- I'm guessing that may have something to do with it?

Comment: So if you take the original code, paste it in an .html file and open it in Chrome, it will actually display just like I expected.  So it would seem the original code does work.

Comment: The original code doesn't work as is: https://jsfiddle.net/v6spb996/ ... it need a height on the body to actually fill the viewport: https://jsfiddle.net/v6spb996/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work with Aurelia (or alone), you should layout the markup like this

```html
<body aurelia-app="main" style="height:100vh;margin:0;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
  <my-template style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;flex-grow:1">
    <div style="display:flex;">Header</div>
    <div style="display:flex;flex-grow:1">Content Area</div>
    <div style="display:flex;">Footer</div>
  </my-template>
</body>
```

where the `<template>`, if it gets rendered, needs to be `<my-template>` for it to work, as the `<template>` tag has a special meaning and won't render visually, see MDN; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template.

Then the `body` (or any main element) needs a height, and here I used `height:100vh`.

Also do note, the `flex-grow` you had on the `<body>` won't apply if not its parent, the `<html>` also has `display: flex`

Comment: Perfect!  Needed the `height:100vh` on the body.  Thanks.